# Does Obito's Mangekyou Sharingan make him invincible?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto, Kakashi and Guy had a battle with Obito. Obito was able to phase through Naruto's attacks, But Kakashi found a weakness, since his own and Obito's Sharingans were connected.

If Kakashi's Sharingan wasn't connected to Obito's. Would Obito have been invincible?

Answer (score 8):

No, Obito has another weakness.

He cannot keep the "Everything goes through me" mode for more than 5 minutes straight. So if they kept going at him without letting him a chance to rest, he should have been dealt with.

However, this is a very hypothetical question, and thus can't be factually answered.

Comment: Okej, Thanks. Is the limit 5 minutes for everyone or is it the limit based on his chakra?

Comment: @Madara any sources that explain this "5 minute" limit?

Comment: @FatalSleep Check the konan vs obito fight.

Comment: Still that's debatable. He could use [Izanagi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi) and escape from death. later replace the blind eye with a fresh sharingan from his [collection](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito's_Laboratory#Laboratory).

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki True, but then he'd lose one of his Kamui eyes permanently.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Do you think losing one kamui eye would decrease the ability ? I guess, the 5 minutes time limit is based on the chakra levels not based on number of eyes. Enlighten me :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha great-great-great-greatgrandson and great-great-great-great grandma shouldn't debate, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Obito only has one eye available for izanami per fight (assuming he doesn't want to go blind), so after he uses it he's pretty vulnerable. Imagine if right after Konan, another shinobi with knowledge of his power was there to keep up the fight. Obito would have been fighting with one sharingan and very low chakra. One on one though he's a pretty tough match--but most S class shinobi are "invincible" in one on one fights. As far as the fight with Naruto and co. with the ten tails--it was for lack of knowledge Naruto and Guy couldn't beat him. Ignorance makes a lot of shinobi look invincible. Remember when we first saw Pain against Jiraiya??

Answer (score -1):

It's completely unknown.

Obito never wielded both eyes so it could be said that his abilities would be enhanced 10 fold if he had both. Perhaps his intangibility time would increase from 5 minutes.

Comment: Correction: Obito did weild both eyes during the 4th SWW. It lets him access dimensional planes. Please consider expanding your answer as it is too short.

Answer (score -1):

Well hes basically invincible. He has a 5 min limit but that's only 5 mins of UNINTERRUPTED phasing, the instant he stops phasing that time limit is reset. So naruto, kakashi, and guy wouldn't be able to counter it by just attacking him for 5 minutes because as shown he stops phasing in between attacks. But I feel like someone as fast as naruto in his prime could potentially counter it or sasuke using his teleporting ability. Also I saw someone say that the naruto crew lacked knowledge and that is not true they knew the basic fact that they had to attack him when he attacked and that's basically all u need to know about kamui because that's the only way to attempt to counter it without using kamui itself.